# Initial paper of the Moore Neighborhood algorithm

Tags: graph-algorithms

I don't exactly know if this is the place to ask it, but I'm looking for the original paper of the [Moore Neighborhood algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood). I need to make a reference to it (or whoever came up with it). I can't seem to find the origin, just other people using it. Does anyone have an idea what I need to cite for this ?

Comment: Perhaps G.A. Moore, "Automatic scanning and computer processes for the quantitative analysis of micrographs and equivalent subjects". Pattern Recognition: Pictorial Pattern Recognition, 1:275-326, 1969.